# Язык C, как именно анализируются *.h файлы при компиляции?

Tags: c, define, macro

Подскажите, как именно анализируются *.h файлы при компиляции?

Я тут экспериментирую с препроцессором.

Задумался над следующей гипотетической штукой:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FOR_START for(;;){
#define FOR_END }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FOR_START

    // Тело цикла.

    FOR_END
}
```

Если ее переделать в:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    #include "FOR_START.h"

    // Тело цикла.

    #include "FOR_END.h"
}
```

Это законный код? И применяются ли такие техники?

Во многих случаях вместо огромного макроса было бы удобно написать код в *.h файл. Но я не совсем понимаю, в какой степени анализируется *.h файл.

С одной стороны, *.h файл может содержать незаконченную конструкцию:

```
for (;;){
```

Но с другой, он не позволяет использовать типы и неизвестные идентификаторы:

```
uint8_t func(void){...};// Ошибка, неизвестный тип uint8_t
```

PS. Интересно было бы услышать, за что мой вопрос заминусовали?

Comment: Первым этапом все, что в `#include` тупо копипастится в то место, где оно указано

Comment: Тупо? Интересный термин.

Comment: Но это никак не отвечает на вопрос относительно того, в какой степени и как именно анализируется содержимое *.h файла.

Comment: никак оно не анализируется. В то место, где у вас указан `include` вставляется содержимое заданного файла. Все. Когда все вставилось - начинается анализ получившегося

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Меня сбила с толку *умная* IDE, которая в описанной ситуации направляет прямиком в *.h файл, а не в строчку с #include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include` ничего не знает о типах, известных или неизвестных идентификаторах.

Все, к чему сводится обработка этой директивы - внести вместо нее содержимое указанного файла.

**ДО** компиляции - потому и **пре**процессор.

Так что хоть

```
for(
#include "init.h"
;
#include "cond.h"
;
#include "post.h"
)
#include "open_brace.h"
#include "close_brace.h"
```

Но такой код в первую очередь будет мешать вам самому...

Comment: Это я понимаю, но я думал, что связанные с проектом *.h файлы как-то да анализируются, а оказывается нет. Значит, даже если в решении находятся *.h файлы, то для проекта/компилятора они являются просто текстом и не более?

Comment: Я не планировал писать такой код, просто заинтересовал вынос кое-какой магии не в макросы, а в *.h

Comment: @Максим я вам больше скажу - для `include` абсолютно все равно, какой файл вставлять, хоть `.jar` его назовите. Главное, чтобы итоговый код получился консистентный

Comment: Ну это я знаю. Просто был недостаточно информирован о том, как именно не  *.c файлы воспринимаются компилятором/решением/IDE.

Comment: @Максим: Как именно они воспринимаются - зависит от компилятора. Скармливание `.h` файла компилятору GCC воспринимается им как просьба выполнить *прекомпиляцию* заголовочного файла.